# iMessage: enable SMS and not MMS

Tags: messages

I have an iPhone and obviously I always use iMessage with friends that have an iPhone. I want my SMS to be sent also if iMessage is not available, so I switched on "Send as SMS" option.

Today I sent an image to a friend and iMessage was no available. If spending for a SMS in ok, I want to send images only when iMessage is available. Is there any option that can enable SMS and disable MMS when iMessage is over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MMS switch *only* disables MMS, not iMessages with picture attachments. So you can turn the MMS switch off to get the behaviour you desire.